# calloutaccessorycontroltapped or prepareForSegue

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, annotations, detailview

i have a map and the map have annotation , and i can see these annotation in table view as a cells then i can see the details for any cell i selected like the master details project in the xcode

like this

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
Object *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
detailsViewController.detailItem = object;
}
```

the code was for the cell in the table view that will push to the details view

but i want the user when he press UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure in the annotation then the Button  will go to the same DetailsViewController that the cell will go to in the table view

is it possible to do this ?

i have read about calloutAccessoryControlTapped but i'm not sure how to make the annotation that have been selected to be the detailItem that i have declared in the DetailsViewController

Thank you : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking. Here's a couple of guesses and their answers:

### How do I perform a segue from a map callout accessory button?

Dragging from controls (table cells, buttons, etc) in IB is a nice way to make segues since UIKit can handle everything for you -- when the control is tapped, it performs the segue automagically. But there are controls you can't create segues from, and times when you might otherwise want programmatic control over performing a segue. For that, you create a segue by dragging *from the view controller itself* in IB; give the segue a unique identifier, and then in your view controller you can call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"]` whenever you want the segue to happen.

In this case, you'd probably call that from within `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`.

### How do I pass my model object to the next view controller in this kind of segue?

Presumably your model objects conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol and you're adding them to the map with `addAnnotation(s):`. In that case, when your map delegate's (presumably your view controller's) `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method is called, the second parameter has a reference to the corresponding `MKAnnotationView`. That class has a property `annotation` which will point back to your model object.

Of course, in this method you're just calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, so you don't yet have access to the destination view controller. So you'll need to hold onto that model object reference (say, in an ivar) for now, and then your `prepareForSegue:sender:` implementation can pass it to the destination view controller.

Comment: Thanks for answer me : ) 
i found this and it's like what you have said
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256883/mapkit-how-to-pass-managedobject-from-mapview-to-mapdetailview)
it's help me with your answer! so Thank you!

Comment: Interesting I had no idea I could drag from a viewController to another. this is really useful thank you

Comment: But how do you wire the segue from the calloutaccessory in the first place?

Comment: You don't. As I've described above, wire the segue *from the view controller*, then write a `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method which calls `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.